# Add keyword to javascript-mode in emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs, self

I want to add, in my `.emacs` and new keyword for `.js` files in order the syntax highlighting highlights the word `self` with same font and color as `this`, because in my `.js` files I make use of the `self` trick to avoid context issues:

```
var self = this;
```

So, I want to see `self` for fast "visual" access as if it were `this` for `js-mode` (or `javascript-mode`, I'm not sure what I'm currently using by default).

What must I add to my `.emacs` to get that changes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using something similar to the `js.el` major mode I have (in emacs 24.5), the mode uses many `defconst` commands to set the font-lock defaults, and I don't see how to change these cleanly, so the simple thing is to add to your `.emacs` file:

```
;; add "self" like "this" as keyword
(font-lock-add-keywords 'js-mode
  '(("\\<self\\>" 0 'font-lock-constant-face prepend)))
```